# configuring date formats with Windows 7/.NET/SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2, date, windows-7

I recently copied a web application to a new install of Windows 7 and SQL Server 2008 R2. The application uses LINQ to SQL. Somewhere along the line the parsing of POSTed date strings got screwed up. When the user enters a date string like `4/23/2011`, the application rejects it, throwing the error `The value '04/23/2011' is not valid for Due.` Due (actually DueDate) is a DateTime field in SQL Server.

This used to work fine. I assumed it was an issue with the machine's OS internationalization settings, so I checked and the short and long date formats are set to `MM/dd/yyyy` and `dddd, MMMM dd,yyyy` respectively, which looks OK to me. The SQL Server database language is set to English.

The partial class for this property looks like this:

```
[DisplayName("Due")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

There must be another date format setting I need to tweak. Where should I be looking?

Note: this may be more correctly a serverfault question, but I think devs are much more likely to run into this issue than sysadmins.

**More info:** `SP_CONFIGURE 'default language'` returns:

```
default language    0   9999    0   0
```

**Also:** the default language for the database login I am using is English.

Comment: where does this get rejected? by SQL Server or before'

Comment: Looks like before (by LINQ To SQL I presume). I can do a query or update directly in raw SQL using '4/23/2011' and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I assumed it was an issue with the machine's OS internationalization settings

No, it uses th USERS internationalization settings as told the server by the browser.

> the application rejects it, throwing the error The value '04/23/2011' is not valid for Due.

And that is purely bad programming. You should always (!) enter dates either through a parameter or in the ISO form which is totally independant, if you really insist on creating your SQL strings yourself. That woudl be 2011-04-23. SQL Server will accept that format regardless of the locales set somewhere on client or server.

Comment: I am not creating SQL strings - I am using MVC's TryUpdateModel. What do you suggest in this case? Also, re: the browsers settings, the application fails using the same browsers/machines that use to work with the old install, so I am not sure you are correct here...